# The diagonal of a rectangle exceeds the length by 2 cm. If the width of the rectangle is 10cm. find the length using pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry

answer according to book is 24 cm and my work got me 9.79 (10^2+b^2=2^2)
what exceeds means exactly here? what is the original value of the diagonal?

Comment: "Exceed" means to be more (longer, larger, heavier, whatever fits the context). "Exceed by $x$" means to be $x$ more. In this case, it means that the diagonal is 2 longer than the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceeds means is longer than.  If the length is $b$ cm then the diagonal is $2$ cm longer; so the diagonal is $b +2$.

In a rectangle if the width is $a$ and the length is $b$ and the diagonal is $c$ you have the formula $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

In this case we have the width is $10$ and we dont know what the length is (so we'll call it $b$) and the diagonal is $b+2$.

So we  have $10^2 + b^2 = (b+2)^2$.

Solve for $b$.

Then the length will be $b$

And the diagonal will be $b + 2$.

Answer (score 0):

You took $2$ cm for a length here, when it is really a difference of two lengths. We'll need some algebra here; call the length $x$. Then the Pythagorean theorem gives
$$(x+2)^2=x^2+10^2$$
which I leave to you to verify gives $x=24$ as given.